# How to calculate x^y (x & y are fixed point numbers) with ABDKMath library? [request of specific example]

Tags: floating-point

Let's say I have 2 decimals numbers, x and y. I have found this answer about how to calculate x^y: [Is there any efficient way to compute the exponentiation of an fractional base and fractional exponent?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50527/is-there-any-efficient-way-to-compute-the-exponentiation-of-an-fractional-base-a/70009#70009) and that part is pretty clear. My question boils down to how to represent, let's say `x = 1.000003453` and `y = 0.000065968`. Could anybody provide a clear example?

Also in this example we have 2 constants, but how do I represent a variable or the output of a function in solidity as fixed or floating point?

Source of library: https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exponential function with fractional numbers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79903/exponential-function-with-fractional-numbers)